# Copy files from local linux computer to amazon aws linux instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

How do you copy files from local linux computer to amazon aws linux instance?

Answer (score 24):

We can do that through scp command shown below:

scp -i testkey1.pem sourcefile  ec2-user@ec2-51-122-239-158.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:outputfile

or if you want to copy a complete directory

scp -i testkey1.pem  -r sourcefolder/  ec2-user@51.122.444.128:~/

- -i is the option for pem file
- ec2-51-122-239-158.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com is the public dns 
  address, You can get this value from aws console of your instance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a GUI approach you can use SFTP. Many programs like [Transmit](http://panic.com/transmit/) for Mac or [Filezilla](http://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Howto) can connect to your instance through SSH by connecting to the public DNS name (found in AWS console).

If you want you can definitely use SCP and it is very reliable as you suggested.